# I have to change a column type in a large mysql table. With this be a slow process

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 15 millions records
I need to change a column type from text to varchar(20)

This column is not indexed or has any foreign keys.

I am wondering if this is a very slow process? Will it be a slow as adding an index or worse?

To add an index to this table takes about 30 minutes.

Is the best way to do this is just an alter table?

Thanks for any help or insights

Comment: You want to optimize by changing data type? If so has the reason for using text no longer extant

Comment: @P.Salmon . i want to change the datatype so i can index it. This is something i have inherited and not sure why is was ever a text field instead of much smaller varchar

Comment: *i want to change the datatype so i can index it.* You may index by a prefix: `CREATE INDEX idx ON table (text_column(20));`

Answer (score 1):

I can say it will take longer than creating one index. Changing a data type requires a full table rebuild, which will copy all the rows and rebuild all the indexes on that table. Just in terms of I/O writes, this must be more than building one index.

No one here on Stack Overflow can predict exactly how long it will take for your alter table. It depends on many factors we don't know, like the server speed, the concurrent load on the server, the size of the table, number of indexes, etc.

Even if you test altering the exact same table with the same number of rows on a test server identical to your production server, this isn't always the same as running the same alter on your production server, because other unrelated query traffic on the server will also affect the performance.

So the only way you can tell how long it will take is to do it, and then tell how long it took afterwards.

However, there's another strategy that I would recommend. Use an online schema change tool, like [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) or [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost). Both of these tools are free, open source, and widely used. They allow you to run an alter table without blocking reads and writes to the original table. The alter is executed in the background, and when it is done, the two tables are swapped. Any changes to data in the original table that happen while the alter is running are also copied to the new table.

If your clients can continue to read and write the table, then the pressure to make the alter take less time isn't so great. In fact, it will probably take somewhat longer to finish than using ALTER TABLE directly, but I expect no one will mind, since they aren't blocked.

I used the former tool in an environment where we altered thousands of tables larger than yours in production during peak traffic, without causing any downtime.

As with any tool, learning to use it takes some time, and there are a few limitations. I recommend trying either of these tools on safe, test tables until you are confident you know how to use it, before using it on your production data.